# How to use DataTable in Thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, thymeleaf

How to use datatable in thymeleaf. i have created a table in which i am creating a `div` inside of `td` for all the user present in `userInfo` list

How can i show only one user record as a div and inside of pagination section display only next and previous buttons.

Currently i am getting error `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined`

I found some answer related to it as dataTables requires a well formed table. It must contain  and . But i just want to display one div and hide other div when next button is clicked new div should be visible and hide the previous one

```
<table id="table_id">
<tr>
 <td th:each="info : ${userInfo}">
   <p th:text=${info.name}></p>
   <p th:text=${info.dob}></p>                                     
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In js i just have written this

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example shows one way in which you can use Thymeleaf to populate a table, and then use DataTables to display one row at a time (with "previous" and "next" buttons):

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

        <style>
            .dataTables_paginate {
                float: left !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div style="margin: 20px; width: 150px;">
            <table id="table_id">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Users</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="info : ${userInfo}">
                        <td>
                            <p th:text=${info.name}></p>
                            <p th:text=${info.dob}></p>                                     
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#table_id').DataTable({
                    "dom": "tp",
                    "ordering": false,
                    "pagingType": "simple",
                    "lengthMenu": [ 1 ]
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This creates a very simple display like this, with almost no CSS styling applied:

[image]

The Thymeleaf iterator needs to be placed in the tably body's `<tr>` tag, not in a cell tag.

The HTML table must be defined with both a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>` section, for DataTables to be able to use it.

The DataTables options are:

`"dom": "tp"` - displays only the table (`t`) and the pagination (`p`) controls.

`"ordering": false` - disables column ordering.

`"pagingType": "simple"` - shows only the "previous" and "next" buttons.

`"lengthMenu": [ 1 ]` - forces DataTables to show only one row at a time