# Output of a large table in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

The Spring-Boot App.
I want to output a table with data from the Book class to html.
Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/books")
public String showBooks(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
  allBooks = bookService.getAll();
  model.addAttribute("allBooks", allBooks);
  return "books";
}
```

I use Thymeleaf.
Here is a snippet of html code:

```html
<table border="1" style="width:250px">
  <tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr th:each="allBooks, state : ${allBooks}">
    <td th:utext="${state.count}">No</td>
    <td th:text="${allBooks.name}">A Book'</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There are more than 100 entries in the Book class.
How do I display them correctly so that they display 10 entries per page?
Thymeleaf is able to do this? Or do I need to use javaScript?

Comment: Thymeleaf itself is a server-side HTML processor. It does not provide support for client-side user interactions (such as navigating from page to page of a table's data). You can use a tool which has paging built-in, such as [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). An example of a basic approach is [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65143110/how-to-use-datatable-in-thymeleaf).

Comment: Alternatively, since you are using Spring, take a look at [Spring Data Pagination](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html).